# How to replicate data from CnosDB single instance to CnosDB cluster?

Tags: cnosdb

I am running several CnosDB single instances on edge side (oil fields) while running one CnosDB cluster in the private cloud.

I used to replicate the data from the single instances by exporting the databases to CSV files via [export command](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/manage/backup.html#syntax)

```
COPY INTO 'file:///tmp/oilfields' FROM oilfields
    FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = 'CSV', DELIMITER = ',');
```

and then transforming all these CSVs through Flink, finally [importing](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/manage/backup.html#import) them in the cloud.

```
COPY INTO oilfields FROM 'file:///tmp/oilfields/'
    FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = 'CSV', DELIMITER = ',');
```

However, this is too much work and not real-time.

Any better to achieve such data replication from edge side to cloud side? Could I try [telegraf](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/reference/ecosystem.html#telegraf-introduction) but I didn't find the input plugin for CnosDB itself.